# XML File- Collapse - Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have created one XMLfile from `XML::Simple` using `XMLout`. When i open the file in IE, all the XML tags are expanded. As the file is huge it is difficult to interpret. Is it possible in Perl (while creating XML) then all tags should be collapsed and not expanded. If not, Can this be handled via some batch script OR i need to use some XML editors/viewers for this where in manually i can choose to collapse/expand. 
`use XML::Simple;

my $xml = XMLout($hashref, RootName => 'Data');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expanded/collapsed view of XML is a property of the viewer, and not part of the XML. Internet Explorer can collapse and expand XML view by element - the control to toggle this is  small, but should be visible on the left of each element's start tag.

Other XML editors and viewers may give you more control, such as default view starting collapsed to a certain level.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I thought the same but wanted to confirm in case if something can be done. Thanks once again